# regex, match character with space only

Tags: regex

I have the following regex in c#:

```
return Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Valid characters are a-z, 0-0, _,., -.

I want to only match the - if it has space towards the left AND/OR right.

For an example:
pavement -roads = should not replace anything (only valid case) (pavement           -roads is fine too)
pavement - roads = the - should be removed
pavement- roads = the - should be removed
pavement -                roads = the - should be removed

Comment: Valid characters are :  a-z, 0-0, _,., -.? It seems these are the invalid characters.. This pavement -roads has space towards the left. And it does not have space towards the right so AND/OR = true. But you say it's valid. I am confused.

Comment: When I pass pavements -@$$@#roads to the above regex, the @$$@# is removed.

Comment: This does not make the example clearer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
return Regex.Replace(str, "( +)-( +)", "\\1\\2", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

This should remove any dashes surrounded by spaces, and keep the spaces untouched.

Comment: I should mention that it should keep the original regex "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+" and just add the modifications neccessary for the requirement above. I tried plugging "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.( +)-( +)]+" and it threw an exception saying parsing regex range in reverse order

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you only want to remove dashes with a space after. Try

```
(?:[^\w. ]|(?:\-(?= )))+
```